# Magnetically shielding an actuator

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

We need to magnetically shield a solenoid that activates this valve (shown below)

[image]

Just slipping a mild steel cap over the end does not do the job, nor appears to have any screening effect at all. Any suggestions for a practical way of doing this? Or any explanation of why a mild steel cap is not working?

Comment: It sounds unlikely that you can close the magnetic path completely that way and some fraction of the field will be measurable outside. The material also has to be thick enough (probably several mm) to have a considerable effect. If you are very sensitive to the magnetic field, you may have to design your own actuator or enclose the entire valve in a fairly thick magnetic shield. The best engineering solution may be to separate the valve from the actuator by a non-magnetic push-rod of considerable length that moves the actuator away from the area that is sensitive to the field.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that the mild steel is not sufficiently permeable (relative permeability is around 100) and is not shielding enough of the magnetic field. You could try soft iron, [mu-metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) or permalloy as alternatives, which are more permeable (relative permeabilities of more than 10,000). Some of these are available in tapes and foils that make it easier to construct the shield. The thickness of the shield also matters, thicker being better.

You should also consider the geometry of your shield - it is probably open on some sides, and may not be working as effectively as you might think. Playing with the orientation of your actuator (if you have this freedom) might help here.

If you have a hall probe (which can be bought super cheap if you're willing to do some DIY-electronics), you can measure the effectiveness of your shield. The manufacturer of your actuator should specify the maximum tolerable magnetic field.

Comment: I think you are correct. The steel is saturating. Going to try mu-metal.